# Changing triangle coordinates in openGL

Tags: android, c++, buffer, opengl-es-2.0

I have a `draw()` method in my `Triangle` class that looks like this:

---

```
protected void draw() {
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Position");
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Color");

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        vertexBuffer.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        0, vertexBuffer);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        vertexBuffer.position(6);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        0, vertexBuffer); // NOTE: A stride of 0 since the data is packed.

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
}
```

---

This `draw()` method is being called constantly in `onDrawFrame()` so my triangle is constantly getting drawn. I want to be able to change the coordinates of the triangle. Note: I am initializing my vertex buffer like so:

---

```
private void init() {
        triangleVertexData = concat(triangleCoords, color);

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangleVertexData.length * 4);

        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();

        vertexBuffer.put(triangleVertexData);

        vertexBuffer.position(0);
}
```

---

My `triangleVertexData` is in the form **{x, y, x, y, x, y, r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a}**

---

My question is, how can I implement a `changeCoordinates(float[] p1, float[] p2, float[] p3);` method?

So far this is what I've come up with:

```
protected void changeCoords(float[] p1, float[] p2, float[] p3) {

        float[] coords = new float[] {p1[0], p1[1],
                                    p2[0], p2[1],
                                    p3[0], p3[1]};

        triangleCoords = coords;

        triangleVertexData = concat(triangleCoords, color);

        vertexBuffer.clear();

        vertexBuffer.put(triangleVertexData);

        vertexBuffer.position(0);
    }
```

However this is not working, at random times I get a BufferOverflowException on the `put()` line and I have no idea why.

Comment: I think you choose difficult way. Why you doesn't implement translation with `Matrix.translateM` method?

Comment: @deathember Yeah I know that this is not the right way to do it but I've written too much code that is dependent on this style of coding. Do you have any idea why my method is not working? I don't see why I get buffer overflow, I've even used the `remaining()` method and it always has 18 elements remaining before I call `put()` which means it shouldn't overflow...

Comment: I recommend to you optimize your code. Really man - do not reinvent the wheel. I never believe that you bad developer,who can't optimize your code. If you doesn't want to do optimization - i can't help you, because my knowledge in GLSL is low.

Comment: I am not translating an entire triangle, it is not that simple. I am moving the triangle one vertex at a time. It stretches the triangle in different ways, I don't think I can achieve this using Matrix.translate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause of the exception is that, the methods `changeCoords()` and `draw()` are not synchronized. Please note that, you are modifying `vertexBuffer` in `draw()` method here:`vertexBuffer.position(6);`. If `changeCoords()` gets scheduled just after that, then there is a problem.

Reply to comment:

Yes. Before executing statement `vertexBuffer.put(triangleVertexData)` in `changeCoords` method, if `draw()` gets called, it will leave only 12 `remaining` in `vertexBuffer`.

You can try one of the following things:

- set position of `vertexBuffer` back to zero before leaving `draw` method. May be just after `..glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, 4,...` statement.
- Use separate buffers for each - vertices and color.

Other things probably I should note..

- Try re-using arrays. Don't allocate them very frequently.
- Have a look at `System.arraycopy` for copying arrays, if it fits your need
- Make absolutely sure that, you do not want to use `translateM`, `scaleM` utililies as mentioned by Jin

Comment: But how can that be so? I have used a System.out.println before the put and it says the vertex buffer is free. Are you saying that the position(6) call is being called BETWEEN my print and put methods?

Comment: Setting the position of vertexBuffer back to zero is already being done when I call vertexBuffer.clear(); I fixed this by the way, you correctly identified the problem. The methods were being called simulataneously from multiple threads. I declared all of the methods using the `synchronized` keyword and it is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would try to move a triangle in this way. The linear algebra methods provided in `android.opengl.Matrix` are made exactly for what you're trying to do.

To translate a triangle (or any set of vertices for that matter), its:

```
 Matrix.translateM(float[] m, int mOffset, float x, float y, float z);
```

and to stretch vertices in different directions it's a scale operation:

```
 Matrix.scaleM(float[] m, int mOffset, float x, float y, float z);
```

Even if you were to implement your coordinate-changing method, that would only work for vertices/colors specified exactly the way your `triangleVertexData` is specified.